# Express router app.all('*', (req, res, next)) does not get executed on ec2 instance for HTTP requests. Getting request timed out error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am running a MEAN stack application. It works fine on my localhost. However, when MEAN stack is deployed on AWS ubuntu server HTTP requests are not getting forwarded to the back-end.

The app.js file looks like:

```
var app = express();

app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.secure) {
    
    return next();
  }
  else {
      
    res.redirect(307, 'https://' + req.hostname + ':' + app.get('secPort') + req.url);

  }
});
```

On my localhost every HTTP request is entering into if(req.secure) loop and respective routers defined in app.js are getting invoked.

However, when i deploy my MEAN stack application on EC2, the control does not enter into the if condition at all.

I have used NGINX reverse proxy to forward the back-end requests are below:

```
server {
  charset utf-8;
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;

  location / {
    root /opt/front-end;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  location /* {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:/3000;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell whats going on without any http codes or errors, are you able to connect at all? Could be a firewall issue since EC2 instances dont open http/https ports automatically

Comment: hi, thanks.. I am getting the error: failed to load resource: The request timed out. Also, i have added inbound rules for port 3443 and 80 in Security at the AWS console

Comment: Timed out sounds most likley to be a firewall issue, make sure that not only your security group in aws allows it but also if you have UFW enabled to make sure that also allows those ports, 443 and 80, if you continue to get the error i would try seeing if your docker container is exposed to the right port, and that that port is being proxied to either port 80 or 443, you have no mention of an SSL certificate but you might also be getting an error because you dont have a certificate installed either

Comment: Thanks dune184 for your response. When I checked, UFW had no rule configured for 443 and 80. I have added those now. Docker container is being shown inactive on my instance. Also, i am using .pem to connect to the instance and have no SSL certificate configured/enabled. I am using public IPV4 DNS provided by aws. Request timeout still persists

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations above. It was a SSL certificate issue. After configuring the certificate entries in the nginx default configuration, everything is working as expected  (both http and https requests).